# "push is not a function" error in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script

I have a code that is supposed to read a google sheet and push these into an array but i keep encountering an error that **proData.push is not a function** What could I be missing in this code?

```
function getData() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Projects").getRange("A1:O").getValues();
  values.shift(); 
  var proData = [];
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    var proData = {};
    proData.project_state = value[0];
    proData.project_name= value[4];
    proData.project_code= value[5];
    proData.end_date= value[2];
    proData.push(proData);
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(proData));
  return proData;
}
```

I will appreciate help in looking at this.

Comment: What are you expecting `proData.push(proData);` to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line tells the whole story:

```
proData.push(proData);
```

You're trying to push an object onto itself?  Clearly this is an indication that something is wrong.  So let's look at where you define `proData`:

```
var proData = {};
```

That at least explains the error.  `proData` is an object, not an array.  And an object indeed doesn't have a function called `push`.  You may have *thought* it was an array, because you defined an identically named array here:

```
var proData = [];
```

But for the line where you call `.push`, how is the system to know which variable you intend for what purpose?  In a higher scope you have an *array* named `proData`, but in the current scope of this operation you obscured that with an *object* named `proData`.  And in doing so made the array inaccessible within the scope of the function passed to `.forEach`.

To avoid confusing both the JavaScript engine and yourself in this matter, simply use different variable names.  Re-naming the variable in the smaller scope has a lower impact, so that's a good candidate.  (Though it's not always the best choice.  If the variable in the higher scope is *semantically* not clear about what it contains then it should be re-named.)

Something like this:

```
values.forEach(function(value) {
  var pd = {};
  pd.project_state = value[0];
  pd.project_name = value[4];
  pd.project_code = value[5];
  pd.end_date = value[2];
  proData.push(pd);
});
```